# Pseudo-randomness of observables

Tags: quantum-mechanics, non-locality

There is a somewhat recent [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.5173) by Colbeck and Renner that, given the assumptions — 1) QM accurately predicts the correct statistical results in experiment (which so far has always been found to be true) and 2) the measurement can freely be chosen — that no extension to quantum mechanics can have improved predictive power.

I've taken basic QM and I just started taking QFT so understanding the paper is somewhat beyond my skills; so perhaps someone can help me with this situation:

Suppose you have a pseudo-random number generator (e.g. it could be any function really as long as its outputs appear random and the appropriate correlations [entanglement] between different positions exist) that is a function of position and time: $F(\vec{x}, t)$.  If you knew the algorithm for this generator, you could plug in the spatial coordinates and time of your experimental measurement*, and get information that allows you to predict the exact* eigenvalue of the linear operator that corresponds to your measurement.

This hypothetical PRNG would be for the whole universe, so I suppose it would count as a non-local hidden variable.

My question is: why does Colbeck and Renner's paper rule out this possibility?

(*Okay, you can't plug in the exact coordinate and time of your measurement because of HUP.  Perhaps you just get *improved* predictive power over QM by giving close enough coordinates and time).

Comment: You might want to look up what is meant by a "cryptographically secure" PRNG: your knowing the algorithm is assumed (all the security resides in the key) and you have a long history of previous outputs and if the generator is secure you can not do better than guessing. 'Course algorithms can not be proven to be secure, but we have a number that have stood up to some pretty sophisticated attacks for years.

Comment: Adding to @dmckee 's comment: PRNGs are designed for many different purposes: [Mersenne Twisters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) give "random" behavior from the standpoint of making many Monte-Carlo simulations work, but actually encode very pithy, simply rules that can be found out easily in attack. [Blum Blum Shub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum_Blum_Shub) on the other hand also encodes very simple rules, but so far have withstood years of attack. Looking at these two contrasts might help to clarify your ideas - I know that is no direct help to your question.